# Extending Javascript with new syntax

Tags: javascript, preprocessor, transpiler

Im working on a project in which i'm trying to simplify the syntax of an older package, i.e.:

I want to convert something like

`digitalPulse(LED2,1,1000)` to `puck.LED.flash("red",1000)`

Where LED2 is a red LED always. There are around 50 of these examples.

After investigating this online everything is pointing to building a transpiler/preprocessor. Is this the best method as these blocks of code will be used within files, an example of their usage could be.

```js
let puck = new Puck();

if(...){
    puck.LED.flash("green",1000);
else {
    puck.LED.flash("red",1000);
}
```

##### Sidenote

This particular example would be converted to

```js
if(...){
    digitalPulse(LED1,1,1000)}
} else {
    digitalPulse(LED2,1,1000)}
}
```

In addition to this there are also

```js
setWatch(function(){
    LED2.set();
}, BTN,{edge:"rising", repeat:true, debounce:50})
```

which should translate to below, which accepts other parsed code in the function such as below: *Some functions such as onPress assume default values like in this case there is no need to specify BTN or the object containing edge, repeat and debounce*

```js
puck.onPress(function(){
    puck.LED.on("red");
}
```

How can I approach this without overcomplicating it as ive already fallen down a rabbit hole of transpilers/preprocessors trying my own tokenization, parsing to generate an AST and transpiling, but ive not been successful and havent been able to find an example of this online to see exactly.

Is there a better approach to this problem can anybody recommend tools to assist with this or with direction of where I should be researching.

Comment: This is not a trivial task, I would suggest using https://esprima.org/ to convert the code to an AST, then modify the AST to your liking and recompiling to JS

Comment: If the goal is to make the legacy library easier for programmers to use then add JSDoc comments to it to generate documentation.  And IDEs like VSC can also use those to provide IntelliSense help with each function.  See: [JSDocs](https://jsdoc.app/)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to migrate a legacy procedural code to modern object oriented Javascript.

The 1st thing is to understand what is the target:

- nodejs: you don't need any preprocessor or transpilers to support Javascript classes
- a web browser: excepting very old version like Internet Explorer, every modern browsers supports Javascript classes. So the following code doesn't need any preprocessor or transpilers:

```js
const div = document.querySelector("div");

class Led {
  constructor() {
  }
  flash(color, time) {
    div.style.backgroundColor = color;
    setTimeout(() => div.style.backgroundColor = "", time);
  }

}

class Puck {
  constructor() {
    this.LED = new Led();
  }
}

const puck = new Puck();

if(Math.random() > 0.5){
    puck.LED.flash("green", 1000);
} else {
    puck.LED.flash("red", 1000);
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px">LED</div>
```

If you really need to target old browser versions, I suggest to use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/usage/) as a transpiler.

Feel free to give more detail so I can give you a more appropriate answer.

Comment: My intention is not to add new syntax but allow for a standalone file to be translated, to the older packages syntax as it adds syntax to standard javascript that is used to run on embedded systems, so my intention is use my custom syntax and convert it to the old packages native code so it can be run on a microcontroller

Comment: Ok, so Babel should be a good solution. Are you able to identify the target from this list that match the syntax supported by your embedded system? https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers